# Efficient way to loop over Tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I want to extract information from multiple xml tags which are structured alike. I loop over every children to append it to a dictionary. Is there a way to avoid a for loop for each tag (like sn and count in my MWE).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

xml = """
    <info>
    <tag>
         <sn>9-542</sn>
         <count>14</count>
    </tag>
    <tag>
         <sn>3-425</sn>
         <count>16</count>
    </tag>
    </info>
    """

bs_obj = bs(xml, "lxml")
info = bs_obj.find_all('tag')


d = {}

# I want to avoid these multiple for-loops
d['sn'] = [i.sn.text for i in info]
d['count'] = [i.count.text for i in info]

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: do u need xml BeautifulSoup? You are using xml already. You can use xpath and xml. BeautifulSoup, by itself, does not support XPath expressions. lxml  has a BeautifulSoup compatible mode where it'll try and parse broken HTML. Why are you using BeautifulSoup? it will be smth like tree.xpath("/tag/sn")  - find all children of tag "tag" which name of the tag is "sn"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach.
There are 2 for loops just for the sake of this solution being dynamic (The only thing to change if you want another tag is the `needed_tags` list):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

needed_tags = ['sn', 'count']
for i in info:
    for tag in needed_tags:
        d[tag].append(getattr(i, tag).text)

print(d)
>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'count': ['14', '16'], 'sn': ['9-542', '3-425']})
```

For your exact example, this can be simplified to:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in info:
   d['sn'].append(i.sn.text)
   d['count'].append(i.count.text)

print(d)
>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'count': ['14', '16'], 'sn': ['9-542', '3-425']})
```